# Problems to display an ul dropdown in a nav-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have problems when I show a list of options in my navbar. I have this code, in it there is a li that has a dropdown that shows me a list of options. The problem is that when I make a hover for the element li the list of options is displayed but the title of the li ...

I have this code:

```
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a></li>
             <li class="cn-dropdown-item pr12">
              <a id="lei_drop">Leistungen</a>
              <ul class="dropdown dropping_off" id="ul_drop">
                                    <li><a href="webdesign.php">Webdesign & Entwicklung</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="corporate-design.php">Corporate Design</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Online Marketing</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lieferdienst Webshop</a></li>
                                </ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">PROJEKTE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">AGENTUR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">KONTAKT</a></li>
        </ul>
```

the css code:

```
      .dropping_off
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .dropping_on
    {
        display: block !important;
    }
```

the js code:

```
     function enter ()
     {    
 $("#ul_drop").removeClass("dropping_off");

  $("#ul_drop").addClass("dropping_on");
     }

     function out ()
     {


  $("#ul_drop").removeClass("dropping_on");

   $("#ul_drop").addClass("dropping_off");
    }


       $('#lei_drop').hover(enter, out);
```

the result is this: 
[image]

there is a distance between PROJEKTE and Leistungen that I do not want. I want that when it is done hover to Leistungen the dropdown unfolds but that the title "Leistungen" does not move.
How can I do this?

I'm using bootstrap and some libraries and plugins like animate.css

Comment: <li class="cn-dropdown-item pr12"> is not closed with </li>

Comment: what is the actual error you want to solve> since it is little bit confusing

Comment: I have found the problem. I needed to complete some bootstrap classes and replace the bootstrap.min.js file and another library that they used

Comment: If you found a solution you could post an answer to your own question or close the question.

Comment: Basically, the parent `li` contains the child list. When the child element is switched to `block` the bounding box of the parent is changed to include the child. The width changes and hence the space between the parent and it's sibling is changed.